# How do I dynamically display the results of my PHP results in separate divs according to their ID?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I'm trying to create a simple e-commerce system. First thing I did was select the rows with the same Order ID from mysql. My table looks like this:

[image]

Now, I'd like to know how I can group them into separate divs, it should look like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT request_date, department_id FROM tbl_requests WHERE request_id=".$_GET['request_id']) ; 
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    echo "" . $row2['request_date'] . "<br/>";
    echo "Order from Department " . $row2['department_id'] . "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<hr/>";
    echo "<br/>";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_requests WHERE request_id=".$_GET['request_id']);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "" . $row['request_details'] . "";
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

I'm sorry if ever this question is incomplete, please feel free to ask me any more questions. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your code is open to SQL injection, by the way.

Comment: Order query results by order id and then manufacturer id, and then implement what’s known as a “control break”.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for every product in array using `Javascript` or `jQuery`(much easier).
This way you can check if your page does contain any existing div with that manufacture id (ie.  #m_1055, #m_1040) or not.

If div does exist, append product in that div (in `jQuery.append()`)

If not, then first append the div with that manufacture id to the document and then append the product to it.

Comment: yea not a good idea to display your whole database in html and use jquery to search it ..